# Jquery Validation radio button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am using jQuery validation in a form an the validation is done on proceeding to next step, not on form submission. All other validation works (text, checkbox etc) but the radio does not. please find the code and the html below. As you will see on the js code I try different ways of writing the same check command on required.

HTML

```
<label for="q11"><input type="radio" value="1" name="question1" id="q11"><span>1</span></label>
```

JS

```
 $('.form').validate({ 
        ignore: ":not(:visible)",
        rules: {
            name     : "required",
            email    : {required : true, email:true},
            country  : "required",
            username : "required",
            password : "required",
            question1: 'required',
            question2: 'required',
            question3: "required",
            question4: {required: true},
            question5: {required: true},
            question6: {required: true}
        },
    });
```

FULL JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current = 1;

    widget      = $(".step");
    btnnext     = $(".next");
    btnback     = $(".back"); 
    btnsubmit   = $(".submit");

    // Init buttons and UI
    widget.not(':eq(0)').hide();
    hideButtons(current);
    setProgress(current);

    // Next button click action
    btnnext.click(function(){
        if(current < widget.length){
            // Check validation
            if($(".form").valid()){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    })

    // Back button click action
    btnback.click(function(){
        if(current > 1){
            current = current - 2;
            if(current < widget.length){
                widget.show();
                widget.not(':eq('+(current++)+')').hide();
                setProgress(current);
            }
        }
        hideButtons(current);
    })

    $('.form').validate({ // initialize plugin
        ignore: ":not(:visible)",
        rules: {
            name     : "required",
            email    : {required : true, email:true},
            country  : "required",
            username : "required",
            password : "required",
            question1: 'required',
            question2: 'required',
            question3: "required",
            question4: {required: true},
            question5: {required: true},
            question6: {required: true}
        },
    });

});

// Change progress bar action
setProgress = function(currstep){
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / widget.length) * currstep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar").css("width",percent+"%").html(percent+"%");      
}

// Hide buttons according to the current step
hideButtons = function(current){
    var limit = parseInt(widget.length); 

    $(".action").hide();

    if(current < limit) btnnext.show();
    if(current > 1) btnback.show();
    if (current == limit) { 
        // Show entered values
        $(".display label:not(.control-label)").each(function(){
            console.log($(this).find("label:not(.control-label)").html($("#"+$(this).data("id")).val()));   
        });
        btnnext.hide(); 
        btnsubmit.show();
    }
}
```

I have checked all other questions here but none solves it.

Comment: Can you try Id instead of name?

Comment: I tried with no luck..

Comment: can you reproduce the issue in fiddle ?

Comment: It's a lot of code because the process is done in a multistep form. if it helps, I am using this script http://www.amitpatil.me/multi-step-form-with-progress-bar-and-validation

Comment: I don't find any issue with the validation code of radio-button http://jsfiddle.net/e7xnszk6/, but  check if the radio button is inside the `<form></form>`

Comment: It is, the thing is that if I put any other validation at the same position, ie text, it works.

Comment: @Shehary I have added the whole JS above, if you add that on the fiddle you created, it shows an error but in my case it does not show anything, it just does not show the error of the value being empty

Comment: @giant Can you put complete HTML code in fiddle and update it n pasted the update link here, may b the problem is in HTML not in JS

Comment: @Shehary here is the updated html code http://jsfiddle.net/e7xnszk6/1/  but css is missing and it's not visible correctly., in any case the code is there

Comment: @giant the only fix you need in your code is change `button` type from `button` to `submit` in HTML http://jsfiddle.net/e7xnszk6/2/

Comment: @Shehary the reason is a button is to work as a "next" to proceed to the next hidden part of the form, if I do submit the form is posted and it actually does not work. Just a note, the issue is only with the radio button, with text fields or checkbox it works fine

Comment: @giant let me have look again

Comment: @giant check here now http://jsfiddle.net/e7xnszk6/3/ with button type `button` i put click function in JS and made some changes in validation code see if this resolve the problem, only validate on next button

Comment: @Shehary here is the full js  http://jsfiddle.net/e7xnszk6/4/  when i update it with the code you wrote it does not work. I thought of using checkboxes and have a maximum of 1 cause I'm not sure what is going wrong

Comment: @giant in jsfiddle.net/e7xnszk6/3 i make 2 changes, the click function is just to check the validation in fiddle, you don't need to use it in your live code and second changes was the radio button required rules, only change those rules in your live code and check, don't use the click function, i use it in fiddle just to check validation. also can you provide the live site link

Comment: @Shehary did the one change, nothing, here is the link http://diyful.com/quiz/

Comment: @giant `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`

Comment: @Shehary yeah, fixed that. sorry. issue is still there :/

Comment: @giant if i change `ignore: ":not(:visible)",` to `ignore:":not(:hidden)",` it start validating, make change in live site and check

Comment: @Shehary changed it on the live site. it does the validation. but it does not proceed. even if you choose something